# Is the storage location "storage" for all Android devices and versions fixed?

Tags: android, storage, android-sdcard

I want to know :

`/storage/sdcard0/` and `/storage/sdcard1/` directory location for all android devices and versions available and unchanged?
Namely, can i use this `/storage/...` in my code?

I want to be sure this is the root of all versions are available or not. !

for example :

```
File root = new File("/storage/sdcard1");
// or
File root = new File("/storage/sdcard0"); // if UNMOUNTED , i know ..

//File[] files = root.listFiles();
//for(File singlFile: files){
    // ...      
//}
```

Is this code is correct? for all android mobile devices?
thanks for help.

Comment: It wont work. The android storage roots are different for different versions and different mobile manufactures.

Comment: @Chandrakanth can i use `/storage/..` from **api 1** to **api 21** ? is correct ?

Comment: No you can't use like that...see the below answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> /storage/sdcard0/ and /storage/sdcard1/ directory location for all android devices and versions available and unchanged?

Absolutely not. They are not even the same for different users on the same device.

**NEVER HARDCODE ROOT PATHS**. Always use methods on `Context`, `Environment`, etc., to get at root paths.

Comment: thanks man, So i how to use `Context` and `Environment` to get internal storage or phone memory place directory --> `/storage/sdcard1` ??

Comment: @grizzly: I have no idea what "phone memory place directory" means. Your choices for storage, in terms of the Android SDK, are [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), and (to a *very* limited extent) [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html). In many cases, you may be better served not working with the filesystem directly, but working with providers (e.g., `MediaStore`).

Comment: hi please help me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33065793/android-lisview-simplecursoradapter-or-arraylist-adapter